# how to config vlans in windows 2008 with virtIO nic

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, vlan

I just installed Windows2008 in my debian OS with kvm. And i install virtIO nic. I just wanna config virtIO nic with vlan. But after search many times. There seems no solution here. So, Is someone here can resolve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tagging is something Windows cannot do http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2286940

From what I have seen, VirtIO does not allow setting a VLAN tag in the guest, however, you can try and use the e1000 NIC emulation instead of virtIO, and install the Intel provided drivers and the PROSet utility, which should be bale to handle dot1q.

I wouldn't recommend following this path, and instead would set up a separate bridge for this VM on top of a tagged interface on the host

Would be great to hear why you must do the tagging in the guests and not on the hosts, like everyone else does

EDIT: Just tried it - PROSet wouldn't install, because it doesn't recognise the emulated e1000 adapter as an Intel adapter, so there goes this chance :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no native support for vLANs in Windows (any version). You have to install 3rd party software.

That said, the usual way to pass a vLAN to a VM is to create the vLAN pseudo-nic in the host OS and bridge it into a VM NIC (with VirtIO or emulated NIC). If you need more specific instructions on how to do this just say so and I'll dig something up for you.

Comment: No kidding? I thought for sure I'd seen VLAN tag options *somewhere* in windows before, but perhaps that was in third-party NIC drivers.

Comment: thanks for your answer. And thanks for rnxrx. So i understand.And I will follow your advice.

Comment: @ErikA, yep not built in; most good NIC drivers have options as you note. Same with link aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

ok if you using an e1000 NIC for tagged-VLANs a little work-a-round follows:

1. download the software from intel.com
2. start the setup, but do not continue!
3. go to the Device Manager and update the Windows driver to the Intel driver (you can find the unpacked package under %temp%\rarXXX)
4. close the Device Manager and continue the setup

now setup will find the NIC and installs Intel ProSet

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish?  You can simply create additional interfaces in kvm and tie them to tagged VLAN's on the host's NIC.

Comment: This is fit for my work. We must use vlan in the vms.

Answer (score 0):

Well.

You probably should create networks on your VM host and attach a virtual interface on that network to your guest.

With libvirt, you probably should create a bridge with a vlan interface. Then, create a new virtual interface on that bridge.